# Get parent node in custom section tree

Tags: javascript, c#, umbraco7

I have a multi level tree in my custom-section of Umbraco 7, where the root node is always the country.

- Denmark

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
- Sweeden

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
- Norway

  - Item 1
  - Item 2

Now, when working with Item 2 of Denmark, i would like to get the node-ID of the root-node (Denmark) so that i know what Country ID i'm working under.

Is there any JavaScript API to recurse back over the node levels, and get the top-most expanded?

Thanks in advance.
Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to use `editorState`
(I'm running Umbraco 7.5.7)

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("Client.Controller",
  function ($scope, editorState) {

    // Get the rootNode out of the path.
    var rootNode = editorState.current.path.split(",")[1];
});
```

Since the path contains the entire structure where the current node is located, the second first node would be the root node.

---

Another solution might be this:
(Haven't tested this myself)
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/73796-how-to-get-the-parentid-of-the-current-node-in-custom-tree-using-angularjs

Which in a simple way states:

> inject appState and treeService into your angular controller
>
> This will get the top most node of the current tree:
> var rootNode = appState.getTreeState("currentRootNode");
>
> This will get the current selected node in the custom tree
> var selectedNode = appState.getTreeState("selectedNode");

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be with Razor:

```
var parentNode = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1);
```

This will give you the root node for the current page, and you can access the properties of the root node as required:

```
int id = parentNode.Id;
```

Comment: Since i am working in a angular-controller for my backend section, razor is sadly not an option. Therefor i need the JS way :) Thank you though.